# Draw lines from x axis and y axis to points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw the line from the point to the x and y axis:

[image: expected result]

Here is the code I used:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA()
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_))
plt.xlabel('Number of Components')
plt.ylabel('Variance (%)') #for each component
plt.title('Explained Variance')

plt.show()
pca = PCA(n_components=0.8)
new_data = pca.fit_transform(x)
pca.explained_variance_ratio_
variance = np.cumsum(np.round(pca.explained_variance_ratio_, decimals=3))
variance
print(abs( pca.components_ ))
```

Here is the result:

[image: what I get]

Comment: I don't see any code here that is trying to draw the line segment.  Have you investigated how to draw lines in matplotlib?  For each point in your line, you can plot additional lines from `(0,y)` to `(x,y)` and `(x,y)` to `(x,0)` in the appropriate color.

Comment: i did try to use 
plt.axvline(x=1.75, color='y')
plt.axhline(y=0.95, color='y')
but still don't know how to do it properly

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what I'm talking about.  Note that I start with the points of the graph, then I "post process" that by adding the additional lines.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = [(0,0), (2,1), (4,3), (6,4)]
xx = [p[0] for p in points]
yy = [p[1] for p in points]
plt.xlabel('Number of Components')
plt.ylabel('Variance (%)')
plt.title('Explained Variance')
plt.plot(xx,yy)
for c,(x,y) in enumerate(points):
    xx = [0, x, x]
    yy = [y, y, 0]
    plt.plot(xx,yy)

plt.show()
```

"Why", you may ask, "did you use enumerate to get a variable you don't use?"  Because I thought I would need that to index into an array of colors.  Here, I'm just relying on the matplotlib defaults for additional lines.

Output:
[image]

Comment: why not  simply set the axis-limits to 0?

Comment: I don't see how that would solve the problem.

Comment: am I correct that the remaining problem is that the horizontal and vertical lines do not extend until the boundary lines?

Comment: I don't know that there are any remaining problems.  The OP has not responded.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw the lines using annotations.

1. find the values of the point `(x, y)` in relative axis-units `(xa, ya)`
2. draw annotation lines from the point `(x, y`) to the axis-boundaries `(xa, 0)` and `(0, ya)`

(note that they will NOT correctly update on zoom... this is also possible but requires a bit more work)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

points = np.array([(0,0), (1,1), (2, 4)])

f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(*points.T)

def add_lines(points):
    f.canvas.draw()      # trigger a draw to make sure transformations are correct
    
    for x, y in points:
        # transform coordinates into relative axis-units (e.g. 0-1)
        xa, ya = ax.transAxes.inverted().transform(ax.transData.transform((x, y)))
        
        # add annotation-lines from the point to the x-axis
        ax.annotate(
            xy=(x, y), xycoords="data",
            xytext=(xa,0), textcoords="axes fraction",
            text="",
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0, color="r"),
            )
        # add annotation-lines from the point to the y-axis
        ax.annotate(
            xy=(x, y), xycoords="data",
            xytext=(0,ya), textcoords="axes fraction",
            text="",
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0, color="g")
            )

add_lines(points)
```

[image]